# Impersonated process will not log on to Oracle with Windows Authentication

Tags: oracle, iis, impersonation, createprocessasuser

I am running a asp .net web service on IIS7. The latter is running on a Windows 2008 R2 Server. IIS7/the web service is configured for asp .net impersonation. The worker process owner is set to NETWORK SERVICE.

The web service invokes sqlplus.exe impersonated with his/her domain account on the server. I can see that through the task manager. However, when sqlplus is started, oracle says the username/password is wrong.

sqlplus.exe is started like this: sqlplu.exe / . This works great if I manually log on the server with the user account and type the statement above, everything works great

Comment: Did this answer your question? If it did, be sure to mark it as answered so the rest of us know that took care of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're running into the "double hop" issue here.

Your first hop is using impersonation from the client's computer to the web server. The second hop is from the web server to your database server, where you're attempting to pass those same credentials along to the database.

When you manually log on and run the sqlplus statement, it's only a single hop from the web server to the database server.

The following is quoted from MSDN. Notice the recommendation to use basic authentication from the client to the web server.

> The double-hop issue occurs when the
>   ASPX page attempts to use resources
>   located on a server that is different
>   from the IIS server. In our case, the
>   first "hop" is from the web browser
>   client to the IIS ASPX page; the
>   second hop is to Active Directory.
>   Active Directory requires a primary
>   token. Therefore, the IIS server must
>   know the password for the client to
>   pass a primary token to Active
>   Directory. If the IIS server has a
>   secondary token, the
>   NTAUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS account
>   credentials are used. This account is
>   not a domain account and has very
>   limited access to Active Directory.
>
> The double-hop using a secondary token
>   occurs, for example, when the browser
>   client is authenticated to the IIS
>   ASPX page by using NTLM
>   authentication. In this example, the
>   IIS server has a hashed version of the
>   password as a result of using NTLM. If
>   IIS turns around and passes the
>   credentials to Active Directory, IIS
>   is passing a hashed password. Active
>   Directory cannot verify the password
>   so it uses NTAUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON
>   for authentication.
>
> If your browser client uses Basic
>   authentication to authenticate to the
>   IIS ASPX page, the IIS server has the
>   client password and can make a primary
>   token to pass to Active Directory.
>   Active Directory can verify the
>   password and authenticate the domain
>   user.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms817871.aspx

Comment: Jason, thank you so much for providing me this. I am not sure if this will work, but it is surely a light in the end of the tunnel. I will look into the article and work further on my code to see if this does the trick. Thanks again.